# data of image from url is nil after unwrapping

Tags: swift, uiimage, urlsession, unwrap

I'm using Swift 4 and trying to get images from my server. Using `ipconfig` in terminal, I know my localhost's ip is `10.43.229.215`.
the following code is to retrieve the image data and turn it into `UIImage`:

```
func GetImage(url:String) {
        let image = String(localIP + url).addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: .urlQueryAllowed)!
        let url = URL(string: image)
        print(image)
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url!, completionHandler: { (data, response, error) in
            if error != nil {
                print("Client error!")
                return
            }
            guard let data = data else {
                print("Error: did not receive data")
                return
            }
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.LensImageView.image = UIImage(data: data)
            }
        }).resume()
    }
```

What I don't understand is that, the `image` string did show the image I want if I copy/paste the string to my browser
(http://10.43.229.215:3000/lensPic/%E5%A4%AA%E5%A6%83%E7%B3%96%E6%9D%8F.png)
However, error appears at the line `self.LensImageView.image = UIImage(data: data)` saying `Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while implicitly unwrapping an Optional value`. 
 I'm really confused about:

1. How can data be `nil` if there is already a `guard let` method?
2. Why can the data be nil is I can show the image through my browser?

Any help is highly appreciated!

Comment: `let url = URL(string: image)`, is it nil? Else is `LensImageView` nil but set as non optional?

Comment: Is LensImageView an implicitly  unwrapped optional?

Comment: UIImage initialiser with data may return nil if the method could not initialise the image from the specified data. The image link you provided is not accessible to check.This is not because the data is nil.

Comment: Your URL is http:// & not https://.  You need to ensure you have set the NSAllowsArbitraryLoads key to YES under NSAppTransportSecurity dictionary in your .plist file.

Comment: I just found out my LensImageView was nil but the data was correct. Thank everyone for your help !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem lies in making a false assumption about what is nil. It has nothing to do with the image or the data. What’s nil is `self.LensImageView`, the outlet property.

Comment: yes, I just figured that out. I'm curious like how and when the ui property is nil? In my case, LensImageView is part of the UICollectionViewCell. I'm not sure when it is not `nil` so I can retrieve image from it